# Error in IntelliJ when building flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, flutter-plugin

I get the error below when trying to build an flutter app in IntelliJ

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:157)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:76)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidTarget(AndroidJpsUtil.java:405)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidJpsUtil.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.builder.AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.computeRootDescriptors(AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.<init>(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:274)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:232)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I am using android sdk 29.

Comment: Try using JDK 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by downloading and using the Android SDK 28.